# Iphone reminder is different

Tags: iphone, ios, reminders

I have IOS 7, and I use the default reminders app.

One of my reminders is different than the others in a good way.  It shows a due date as well as an alert time; and the task includes the name of someone in my contacts and it offers to call them when I click the reminder.

[image]

[image]

For the life of me, I can't recreate this.  Anyone know how I did it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

When receiving a call you can either **Decline** it, **Accept** it, **Respond with a text message instead of answering** (by pressing the *Message* button) or **Remind yourself to return the call** (by pressing the *Remind Me* button).

When tapping the *Remind Me* button, two options are displayed: *Remind me later* or *Remind me whenever I leave this place*.

The reminder you're referring to in your question, is one of the *Remind me later* kind.